# Where is "nvinfer.h" from tensorrt located?

Tags: c++, nvidia, tensor, tensorrt

I have been trying to compile a basic tensorRT project on a desktop host -for now the source is literally just the following:

```
#include <nvinfer.h>

class Logger : nvinfer1::public ILogger
{

} glogger;
```

Upon running `make`, though, I receive the following message:

```
fatal error: nvinfer.h: No such file or directory  #include <nvinfer.h>
```

The error is correct, too - I used `locate` to try to find it, but there's nothing on my machine that matches. I followed the install instructions for desktop installation of TensorRT 2.1 as described here: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-tensorrt-download

So my question is, does anyone know where nvinfer.h is *supposed* to be? In other words, am I missing a needed package that contains it, or did I miss something else that's essential?

Small addendum: one thing I noticed is that libgie1 is not installed, and it was not included as a debian with the provided TensorRT download like the other packages such as gie-dev were.

Comment: Before using `locate`, if you recently added new files is a good practice to run `sudo updatedb`, if the file is on the pc you should see it after. Anyway googling a bit it looks like the header your looking for is *<NvInfer.h>*, caps matters.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Feeling a little silly for missing something like that!

Comment: You can accept the answer then ;)

Comment: where was the file lcoated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using `locate`, if you recently added new files is a good practice to run `sudo updatedb`, if the file is on the pc you should see it after.

Anyway googling a bit it looks like the header your looking for is **NvInfer.h**, caps matters.